# Как сделать поиски статей на сайте?

Tags: html, python, django

Есть вариант с помощью order_by или filter. Нужно сортировать данные из базы данных точнее статьи. И еще выводить данные по поиску в шаблон . Поиск должен проходить по названию статьи

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default="default_value")
    tags = TaggableManager()
    article_like = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    article_dislike = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    view = models.IntegerField(default='0')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Моя функция поиска хз работает она ли ? views.py

```
def post_search(request):
    form = SearchForm()
    if 'query' in request.GET:
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        search = request.GET['username']


        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            results = SearchQuerySet().models(Articles).filter(content=cd['query']).load_all()

            total_results = results.count()
    return render(request,
                  'news/posts.html',
                  {'form': form,
                   'search': search,
                   'cd': cd,
                   'results': results,
                   'total_results': total_results})
```

Answer (score 0):

Фильтруете по `filter()` методу, передав ему `lookup`ы. Для поиска вам нужет `__icontains`

```
User.objects.filter(username__iscontains="Челове")
```

Сортировка через `order_by`, передаете назнаниве поля и символ направления сортировка (по убыванию - `-`).

Вывод в шаблоне - передаете в контекст все, что там нужно вывести и выводите конструкциями `{% for x in y %} ... {% endfor %}` и `{{ variable }}`

---

Прошу таки прочитать документацию и пройти туториал